# Temporary folder access denied

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, local-storage

I started with UWP platform apps and I want create new folder in Temp folder:

```
StorageFolder temporaryFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
temporaryFolder = await temporaryFolder.CreateFolderAsync
    (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.Combine(temporaryFolder.Path, fileName)),
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Everything looks OK, but when I want to decompress a ZIP file, which is in Temporary folder into folder which one I created then I give exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\cebff192-8162-4800-9f9c-b3ce1ca8849f_5gyrq6psz227t\TempState\1' is denied.

My question is simple: How I can create a new folder in Temp to which I can write?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the file in the temporary Folder, but it depends on how you access it. When you access the file, please avoid using the file path. See this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/

To open and read a file in the temporary app data store, use the file APIs, such as `Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFileAsync`. You can get more details about the temporary folder from [Temporary app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#temporary-app-data).